# Google Colab - Not able to import API key file

Tags: google-colaboratory, api-key, cds.copernicus

I have a code in Google Colab which uses a Python package called Atlite, which in turn retrieves data from the Climate Data Store (CDS) through the use of an API key.

When running this code in Python I just need to have the file containing the key saved in a specific folder and then the code runs perfectly fine.

When I try to run the code in Google Colab the following error arises:

**Exception: Missing/incomplete configuration file: /root/.cdsapirc
**

I have the file ".cdsapirc" in my computer but when I try to import it to the "/root" folder in Google Colab it just does not get imported. I can import a .py file, but when I try to import the ".cdsapirc" file (which is basically a txt file) it does not work.

Could someone please help me to solve this issue?

Thank you!

Regards,

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If uploading the `.cdsapirc` file doesn't work, you could try creating it inside Google Colab using a simple Python script:

```py
uid = "<your uid>"
apikey = "<your api-key"

with open("/root/.cdsapirc", "w") as f:
    print("url: https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api/v2", file=f)
    print(f"key: {uid}:{apikey}", file=f)
```

You can get the `uid` and `apikey` either from CDS after logging in or you open you local `.cdsapirc` file and look them up there, see [here](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api-how-to) for more information.

There might be a nicer solution by someone more familiar with Google Colab though.

Comment: It worked perfectly fine! I had tried unsuccesfully with a similar solution from another post here in SO, but this Python script solved the problem. Thank you!